# Can't add a button to a panel extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have strange problem. I had simple view which was showing well, as soon as I try to add a button, and try to open my web app, nothing is displayed, here is relevant code, anyone can see what is wrong with it?

```
/**
 * This class is the main view for the application. It is specified in app.js as the
 * "autoCreateViewport" property. That setting automatically applies the "viewport"
 * plugin to promote that instance of this class to the body element.
 *
 * TODO - Replace this content of this view to suite the needs of your application.
 */
Ext.define('Myapp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'Myapp.view.main.MainController',
        'Myapp.view.main.MainModel'
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',


    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Child Panel 1',
            height: 100,
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            items: [
             {
               xtype: 'button',
               text: 'Create',
               itemId: 'createStudentID',
               handler: onClickButton
            }]

        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Child Panel 2',
            height: 100,
            columnWidth: 0.5
        }
    ]
});
```

Controller:

```
/**
 * This class is the main view for the application. It is specified in app.js as the
 * "autoCreateViewport" property. That setting automatically applies the "viewport"
 * plugin to promote that instance of this class to the body element.
 *
 * TODO - Replace this content of this view to suite the needs of your application.
 */
Ext.define('Myapp.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    requires: [
        'Ext.window.MessageBox'
    ],

    alias: 'controller.main',

    onClickButton: function () {
        Ext.define('Student',
        {
            name: 'unnamed',

            getName: function () {
                return "Student name is" + this.name;
            }
        });

        var studentObj = Ext.create('Student');
        studentObj.getName();
    }


});
```

I am really confused. If I remove button and its handler I can see my two panels

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing handler to listener

```
 items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Child Panel 1',
            height: 100,
            columnWidth: 0.5,
            items: [
             {
               xtype: 'button',
               text: 'Create',
               itemId: 'createStudentID',
               listeners: {
                   click: 'onClickButton'
               }
            }]

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open the browser console, which will tell you that

```
onClickButton is undefined
```

Such an error message would be useful to the reader... or to you.

Comment: The console didn't say that. check my answer

Comment: It almost certainly would have said that, if that was the code you had in your OP.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli: it said something different, I will double check tomorrow, my answer solved it